# How to transfer some files when creating a VirtualBox with Veewee

Tags: ruby, virtualbox, veewee

I'm building a virtual box with Veewee and I want to have a script that calls another helper script on the newly created box.

The only way I know is to provide the main script and the helper script in the `postinstall-files` section of the `definition.rb`, like this: 
`:postinstall_files => [ "main.sh","helper.sh"]`

My problem is that Veewee is trying to execute all the scripts, including the helper script (which I don't want).

So I'm interested if there is another way of transffering my `helper.sh` script on the VM, in order to be called from the `main.sh` script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [veewee build hooks](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee/blob/master/doc/build_hooks.md) like this:

```
Veewee::Definition.declare({
  :hooks => {
      :before_postinstall => Proc.new { definition.box.scp('/tmp/helper.sh', '/home/veewee/helper.sh') }
  }
})
```